# c3.js bar, spline charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I don't want the line and the number 0 to show up on the x axis.Anyone knows how to get rid of them? On the html I am able to find them but they are defined in the library(c3.js).

```
<g class="tick" transform="translate(207, 0)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <line y2="6" x1="0" x2="0"></line>
    <text y="9" x="0" transform="" style="text-anchor: middle; display: block;">
        <tspan x="0" dy=".71em" dx="0">0</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

I added this image to show what I exactly don't want to show up:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a c3 user myself. However, c3 is built using d3... thus, a simple d3 block can remove any tick from the x axis with a value of 0.

Put this at the end of your code:

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-axis-x .tick").filter(function(d) {
    return d === 0;
}).remove();
```

What it does: it selects everything with a class `tick` inside a class `c3-axis-x`, which are the x axis ticks. Then, it filters any tick with a value of zero, and removes it.

Comment: I know d3 as well, I am so mad at myself about why I didn't think about it. 
Thank you it worked :)